# Как правильно посчитать scrollLeft?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такие табы. Как правильно посчитать на сколько сдвигать скролл, при активации скрытых вкладок (т.е. те которые идут после "Вкладочка еще").

```
var tabNavigation_width = parseInt($tabNavigationContainer.width()); // ширина навигационной строчки
var selected_position = parseInt($tabNavigationItem_selected.position().left); // позиция выделенной вкладки относительно родителя
var selected_width = parseInt($tabNavigationItem_selected.outerWidth(true)); // ширина выделенной вкладки

if ((selected_position + selected_width) > tabNavigation_width) {
    $tabNavigationContainer.scrollLeft($tabNavigationContainer.scrollLeft() + selected_width);
}
```

Делал так и по другому, все как то не так работает.